# Drill through report, go to report action not loading avaible reports VS2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, report

Hi Im trying to make a drill through report, I'm new with reports, my problen is when I try to link a textbox and choose the "go to report" action, it does not load the dropdown list that show the available reports. I typed the path but still won't work. I can set the parameters because it does not recognize the report's path.

Answer (score 0):

If the sub-report is located in the same project as the main report then you should see a report selection with parameters. Make sure you have built or deployed the sub-report. If the sub-report is located in another ssrs project then you will have to manually enter the link and all parameters. You can enter any location and any parameter for sub-reports. The dialog is just a convenience.